# wavedec does not returning any coefficients in python using pywt library

Tags: python, pywt

i used wavelet decomposition command in python using pywt library but it does not return any coefficients. my code is given below .

```
import numpy as np
import pywt as pywt

(e,f)=pywt.wavedec(y,'db12' ,level=2)
print("e:"+str(e))
print("f:"+str(f))
```

I also tried with `pywt.dwt(y,' db12', level=2)` it is also not returning any coefficients

it returns a null output, where y is a matrix contains my input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried reproducing your results with a random (discrete) signal like so:

```
import numpy as np
import pyw

x = np.random.randint(0,100,500)

y = pywt.wavedec(x, 'db12', level=2)
(e,f) = pywt.dwt(x, 'db12')
```

I noticed two things: For a 1D signal, `wavedec` returns more than two coefficient arrays, as also mentioned in the [docs](http://pywavelets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/dwt-discrete-wavelet-transform.html#multilevel-decomposition-using-wavedec). Similarly, the `dwt` function does not know the keyword `level=`, but works just fine with the command specified above. 
Hope that helps